# How to not impute NaN values with pandas cut function?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use the cut function to convert numeric data into categories.  My input data may have NaN values, which I would like to stay NaN after the cut.  From what I understand reading the documentation, this is the default behavior and the following code should work:

```
intervals = [(i, i+1) for i in range(101)]
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(intervals)
pd.cut(pd.Series([np.nan,0.5,10]),bins)
```

However, the output I get is:

```
>(49,50]
 (0,1]
 (9,10]
```

Notice that the `NaN` value is converted to the middle interval.

One strange thing is that it appears as though once the number of intervals is 100 or less, I get the desired output:

```
intervals = [(i, i+1) for i in range(100)]
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(intervals)
pd.cut(pd.Series([np.nan,0.5,10]),bins)
```

output:

```
>NaN
 (0,1]
 (9,10]
```

Is there a way to specify that I don't want NaN values to be imputed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a bug that originates from `numpy.searchsorted()`:

- [pandas-dev/pandas#31586](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31586) - pd.cut returning incorrect output in some cases
- [numpy/numpy#15499](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15499) - BUG: searchsorted with object arrays containing nan

As a workaround, you could replace `np.nan` with some other guaranteed missing value, e.g. `.replace(np.nan,'foo')`:

```py
intervals = [(i, i+1) for i in range(101)]
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(intervals)
pd.cut(pd.Series([np.nan,0.5,10]).replace(np.nan,'foo'),bins)

0            NaN
1     (0.0, 1.0]
2    (9.0, 10.0]
dtype: category
```

Comment: That's a good idea.  I'm currently creating a mask looking for missing values ahead of time and then setting it to missing after the cut.  Mainly wanted to make sure I'm not missing a parameter that would fix it in one fell swoop